# A question about a paper by Gilmer on union-closed sets conjecture

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, entropy, conjectures

In the [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09055) by Justin Gilmer, the following identity is assumed to hold: given finite random variables $X, X' \in \{0,1\}; C, C' \in \{1,..,M\}$, such that the pairs $(X, X')$, $(C, C')$, $(X, C')$, $(X', C)$ - but not $(X, C)$, $(X', C')$ - are independent, we have:

$$P(X = 0, X' = 0 | C = c, C' = c') = P(X = 0 | C = c) * P(X' = 0 | C' = c')$$
Specifically, in Lemma 1 (the restated version, page 4) and Lemma 5 (the first equation of the proof, page 8). My questions are:

1. Am I correct in assuming that this identity is necessary for the derivation of said resutlts?
2. Are the given independence conditions enough for this identity to hold true?

EDIT: I should've reversed the order of the questions - question 2 is the main question I'm looking to get an answer to.

EDIT 2: it is also known that pairs $(X,C)$ and $(X',C')$ are identically distributed, specifically:
$$P(C=c) = P(C'=c)=q(c),\ P(X=x|C=c) = P(X'=x|C'=c) = p_c$$

Comment: I cannot answer your Q1 (but the answer is likely yes) but $P(X=x, X'=x'|C=c, C'=c') = E(1(X'=x')P(X=x |X'=x',C=c, C'=c')|C=c, C'=c') =P(X=x |C=c)E(1(X'=x')|C=c, C'=c') = P(X=x |C=c)P( X'=x'|C=c, C'=c') = P(X=x |C=c)P( X'=x'|C'=c')$. This uses only the tower rule and pairwise independence.

Comment: @Galton How do you remove "$C=c$" from the conidtion part of the last equation? I'm guessing you're using the pairwise independence somehow, but I can't get how exactly.

Comment: Per Lemma 1 in the paper you linked, $(X', C')$ is a iid copy of $(X,C)$. In words, knowledge of $C=c$ contains no information about $X'$ even when we know $C'=c'$. If you write the conditional expectation as $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ with $B = \{C=c, C'=c'\}$, you can factor out the event $C=c$ both in the denominator and the numerator.

Comment: @Galton forgot to mention they are identically distributed, added to the info. But are we sure they are also independent as pairs? They are defined a tiny bit vague in that regard in Lemma 1, and for the purposes of Theorem 1, they might as well be. Or is there a way to prove their independence as pairs from the pairwise independence of their components?

Comment: Gilmer's intention is that $(X, C)$ and $(X',C')$ are independent.

Comment: As stated in the lemma, $C$ and $C'$ are iid, then $X$ is drawn conditional on $C$ (independent of everything else) and $X'$ is drawn in the same way conditional on $C'$ (independent of everything else), so $(X,C)$ and $(X',C')$ are iid copies. No value of $(X,C)$ contains any information about $(X',C')$ and vice versa. I do not believe you can just get away with comparing just two variables because you always will have at least three variables to compare at the same time.

Comment: @Sean Eberhard Got it, thanks!